# Magento 2 What is the path component after rest /rest/<default|wholesale>/V1/...?

Tags: magento2.2, rest-api, paths

I have a multi-store setup, each store view has its own domain, and I just noticed on order-place Magento calls this API

https://example.com/rest/**wholesale**/V1/carts/mine/payment-information

and I was just wondering where that gets parsed and what does it specify.

I've already went thru **\Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest** and resolver
and couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the official [API  documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/)

Comment: ...really? Just a link to the docs? No insight? No clarification? No original contribution whatsoever? Was the Question "Where can I find the official documentation?"